# how to measure temperature of the distant star

Tags: star, temperature

As part of small project i want to measure temperature of the distant star on basis of optical observations. so by what exact method i can do it? which instruments will be necessary? what is the precision of the experiment?

Answer (score 1):

To measure the surface temperature of a star it is used is it's **black body spectrum**. You would have to get the light curve of the light from tat star and then by checking it's peak you could guess its temperature.

I really don't know which instruments to use to get the light curve from a distant star but you could use a tool like this one for the final conversion: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/blackbody/animations/blackbody.html